# Error: [mapper_parsing_exception] Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters

Tags: indexing, parseexception

i have some problem with this code ,evrytime i try to index it, it display the error:

"Error: [mapper_parsing_exception] Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters: [document : {dynamic=false, properties={alertStatus={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}, orderNumber={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}, crmNumber={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}, triggerValue={type=float}, SLPOSX={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}, blockAlert={type=date}, startAlert={type=date}, neocaseId={type=integer}, path={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}, startInterval={type=date}, alertClass={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}, @version={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}, host={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}, subsidiaryId={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}, company={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}, barcode={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}, endInterval={type=date}, alertCode={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}, SLPONR={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}, customerNumber={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}, message={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}, endAlert={type=date}, tags={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}, @timestamp={type=date}, region={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}, facility={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}}}]"

does anyone have a clue ?
thanks

msg.payload={

```
"mappings": {

    "document": {
        "dynamic": false,
        "properties": {
            "alertStatus": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "ignore_above": 256,
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            },
            "orderNumber": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "ignore_above": 256,
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            },
            "alertClass": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "ignore_above": 256,
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            },
             "alertCode": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "ignore_above": 256,
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            },

            "subsidiaryId": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "ignore_above": 256,
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            },
            "crmNumber": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "ignore_above": 256,
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            },
            "triggerValue": {
                "type": "float"
            },
            "neocaseId": {
                "type": "integer",
            },
            "SLPONR": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "ignore_above": 256,
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            },
            "SLPOSX": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "ignore_above": 256,
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            },
            "blockAlert": {
                "type": "date"
            },
            "startAlert": {
                "type": "date"
            },

            "customerNumber": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "ignore_above": 256,
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            },

            "message": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "ignore_above": 256,
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            },
            "endAlert": {
                "type": "date"
            },
            "tags": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "ignore_above": 256,
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            },
            "path": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "ignore_above": 256,
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            },

            "@timestamp": {
                "type": "date"
            },
            "startInterval": {
                "type": "date"
            },
            "@version": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "ignore_above": 256,
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            },
            "host": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "ignore_above": 256,
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            },
            "company": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "ignore_above": 256,
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            },
            "region": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "ignore_above": 256,
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            },
            "barcode": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "ignore_above": 256,
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            },
            "facility": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "ignore_above": 256,
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            },
            "endInterval": {
                "type": "date"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

};
return msg;

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
"type_name": {                <--- add the type name   
    "properties": {             <--- enclose all field definitions in "properties"
```